# Setting linenothreshold globally

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

The option [linenothreshold](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/markup/code.html#line-numbers) allows one to control the minimum number of lines a code block must have in order to generate line numbers for it. I would love to be able to specify this globally (e.g. in `conf.py`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things that can be added in `conf.py` is

> #### [rst_prolog](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/config.html#confval-rst_prolog)
>
> A string of reStructuredText that will be included at the beginning of every source file that is read. *New in version 1.0*

So if you add something like

```
rst_prolog = '''
.. highlight:: python
   :linenothreshold: 0

'''
```

that will do what you want.

And yes, it really is `rst_prolog` not `rst_prologue`.